# How to set up driver globally for selenium tests from setUp method in unittest

Tags: python, selenium, python-unittest

Could you please explain, why the DRIVER is equaled to None in the decorator auto_login. But DRIVER from setUp method goes first in output when I print it from setUp and auto_login methods. 
And how can I set up driver globally from setUp method.

```
DRIVER = None

class BaseTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        global DRIVER
        DRIVER = webdriver.Firefox()
        print("DRIVER setUp: ", DRIVER)

    def tearDown():
        .....
```

And decorator

```
def auto_login(email, password):
    def create_dec(func):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            print("DRIVER IN DEC: ", DRIVER)
            login(DRIVER, email, password)
            func(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper
    return create_dec
```

It is how I use decorator for test

```
class Test(BaseTest):

EMAIL = "xxx@gmail.com"
PASSWORD = "xxxxx"
@auto_login(email=EMAIL, password=PASSWORD)
    def test_1(self):
         ......
```

Output:

```
DRIVER setUp:  <selenium.webdriver.firefox.webdriver.WebDriver (session="e1f7fa5fa4137305c4587535b20b849c")>
DRIVER IN DEC:  None
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you don't have `DRIVER` defined in scope.

```
def auto_login(email, password):
    def create_dec(func):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):

            global DRIVER # <--- What happens if you add this line?

            print("DRIVER IN DEC: ", DRIVER)
            login(DRIVER, email, password)
            func(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper
    return create_dec
```

Comment: Yes, it did not help

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
DRIVER = None
class BaseTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        global DRIVER
        DRIVER = webdriver.Firefox()
        self.DRIVER=DRIVER 
        print("DRIVER setUp: ", DRIVER)
        return DRIVER

    def tearDown():
        .....
```

And in your Test Class

```
class Test(BaseTest):
DRIVER=BaseTest.DRIVER

EMAIL = "xxx@gmail.com"
PASSWORD = "xxxxx"
@auto_login(email=EMAIL, password=PASSWORD)
    def test_1(self):
         ......
```

Comment: It shows error ` AttributeError: type object 'BaseTest' has no attribute 'DRIVER'`